# C# method overloading without rewriting content

Tags: c#, methods

I have multiple classes, but all of them have a variable with the same type and name. Then, I have a method that takes the value of the variable I mentioned before, and process it in the same way no matter what the input type was.

Here are example:

```
class A{ int i; }
class B{ int i; }
class C{ int i; }
```

This is currently how I write the method that process the value of the int i from each class

```
int foo(A input) { return input.i*2; }
int foo(B input) { return input.i*2; }
int foo(C input) { return input.i*2; }
```

That's a lot of writing just for a different input type, so how do I do method overloading without rewriting the content of the method?

An image of what I was looking for:

```
int foo(A input),foo(B input),foo(C input) { return input.i*2; }
```

Comment: You can define a common [`interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) and use that as parameter type for the method: `public interface IHaveNumber { int i { get; set; } }` `public int Foo(IHaveNumber input){ ... }`

Comment: @germi I think with c#8 you can even have default implementations in an interface. The downside of this is it goes against what an interface is supposed to be.

Comment: @EpicKip true, but I'd rather not point a beginner towards that, as it's confusing enough as it is (even for people with more experience).

Comment: @germi Totally agreed. I know of the existence but refuse to use it as it adds unpredictability for others when they read my code. IMO an interface should **only** be a contract and not have an implementation. I'd suggest people use a base class if they want that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest and most idiomatic way would be to define an [`interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) like this:

```
public interface IHaveNumber //or whatever you want to call it
{
    int i { get; set; } // I would propose a better name for this...
}

public int Foo(IHaveNumber input)
{
    //whatever ...
}

public class A : IHaveNumber
{
    public int i { get; set; }
}
```

Another possibility is to have (e. g.) `B` and `C` derive from `A` and define `Foo` as taking the base class:

```
public class A { public int i { get; set; } }
public class B : A { }
public class C : A { }

public int Foo(A input){ ... }
```

Generally I think it would be helpful to have a look at the documentation regarding [`polymorphism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism) and [`inheritance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance).

Answer (score 2):

How about creating an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class Calculate
{
    public abstract int input { get; set; }
    public virtual int  foo() { return input * 2; }
}
```

And other classes like the following:

```
class A: Calculate {       
    public override int input { get ; set ; }
}
class B : Calculate
{
    public override int input { get; set; }
}
class C : Calculate
{
    public override int input { get; set; }
}
```

Now you don't need to pass anything to get the same job done, just call the method like the following:

```
A aInstance = new A() { input = 10 };
aInstance.foo();
```

You can check this [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wSimK6) also for usage reference

Comment: thanks for the help ! although i doesn't know some part of the code yet because i'm a beginner at c# , but from looking the code closely , i understand what the code do. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

make a parent class with foo() method, then make class A, B, C that inherit from that parent class..

Answer (score 1):

You could use a base class that would your other classes would then inherit

For example:

**Base.cs**

```
public abstract class Base
{
   int i {get;set;}
}
```

**ClassA.cs**

```
public class ClassA: Base
{
  //Put your class specific variables in here
  string name {get;set;}
}
```

**ClassB.cs**

```
public class ClassB: Base
{
  //Put your class specific variables in here
  int age{get;set;}
}
```

**Method**
Then when writing the method you can set parameter to be the base class

```
public int Calculate(Base base)
{
   return base.i * 2;
}
```

Comment: okay thank you for helping :)) i may use this sometimes depends on situation

Comment: No problem, I guess this could be helpful in cases where the method isn't part of the class it's self